# Pandas: Drop NA rows based on shared column values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, drop

I have the following dataframe

[image]

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Country": ["A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B"],
    "Year": [2020, 2020, 2021, 2021, 2020, 2020, 2021, 2021],
    "Category": [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2],
    "Count": [np.nan, np.nan, 1, 2, 3, np.nan, 5, 6]
})
```

I want to drop all values that share values for `Country` and `Year` column and have a `NaN` value in column `Count`. So in this case, row ids 0 and 1 are to be removed (note that row 5 should not be removed).

Can this be achieved without looping, with some inbuilt pandas function?

The following code achieves the desired result, but it is quite inefficient (the real dataframe is much larger):

```
for country in df.Country.unique():
    for year in df.Year.unique():
        if df[(df.Country==country) & (df.Year==year)].Count.isna().all(): 
            df.drop(df[(df.Country==country) & (df.Year==year)].index, inplace=True)
```

Is there a better, more efficient approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `groupby` and `filter` to keep only groups where 'not every count is null'.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Country": ["A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B"],
    "Year": [2020, 2020, 2021, 2021, 2020, 2020, 2021, 2021],
    "Category": [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2],
    "Count": [np.nan, np.nan, 1, 2, 3, np.nan, 5, 6]
})

df.groupby(['Country','Year']).filter(lambda x: ~x['Count'].isnull().all())
```

Output

```
Country  Year  Category  Count
2       A  2021         1    1.0
3       A  2021         2    2.0
4       B  2020         1    3.0
5       B  2020         2    NaN
6       B  2021         1    5.0
7       B  2021         2    6.0
```

Comment: Equivalently `df[df.groupby(["Country", "Year"]).Count.transform("count").ne(0)]`.